# Routing Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rutas

Saludos mi problema es el siguiente: 
Estoy manejando rutas con angular de esta forma:

```
<a class="opcion-menu-navbarSec" [routerLink]="[menu.vista]">Gestion Usuarios</a>
```

en donde "menu.vista" es la ruta que se debe agregar

la ruta debe quedar "modulo/seguridad/gestion-usuarios", pero en vez de añadirse la ruta se coloca solo
"gestion-usuarios"

pero si pongo de esta forma:

```
<a class="opcion-menu-navbarSec" [routerLink]="'gestion-usuarios'">Gestion Usuarios</a>
```

ahi si se pone la ruta como debe ser:"modulo/seguridad/gestion-usuarios"

espero me puedan ayudar porque he pasado mucho tiempo y no doy con el error

Answer (score 1):

los [] son para hacer routerLinks dinamicos, es decir, aquellos donde pasarás
información en el url

el primer valor colocado es el relativo de la dirección:
En este ejemplo puedes ver que el primer valor es la ruta relativa y los otros 2 datos son los que utilizaré.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo que puedes:

```js
//ir apilando cada lugar
menu{
  vista: '/user/bob'
}
```

```html
<a class="opcion-menu-navbarSec" [routerLink]="[menu.vista]">Gestion Usuarios</a>
```

por otro lado, tambien podrias insertar un hijo

```js
const appRoute: Routes = [
  { path: 'seguridad', component: SeguridadComponent, children: [
    { path: 'gestion-Usuarios', component: GestionUsuarioComponent}
]
```

Espero que te sirva :)

Answer (score 0):

Si colocas `/` al principio de la ruta angular creera que senalas la raiz y por ende convertira a `tuDominio.com/gestion-usuarios`

Si lo que quieres es usar la ruta relativa estando en `tuDominio.com/modulo/seguridad/` a tu `menu.vista` deberia contener `gestion-usuarios` unicamente y no `/gestion-usuarios`

De la documentacion:

> If the first segment begins with ./, or doesn't begin with a slash,
>   the router will instead look in the children of the current activated
>   route.
>
> ### Traduccion
>
> Si el primer segmento empieza con `./`, o no empieza con una barra inclinada el "router"
>   buscara en cambio en el hijo de la ruta activada.

Puedes ver mas sobre esto [en este link](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink#description)